# Count property vs Count() method?

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, count

Working with a collection I have the two ways of getting the count of objects; `Count` (the property) and `Count()` (the method). Does anyone know what the key differences are?

I might be wrong, but I always use the `Count` property in any conditional statements because I'm assuming the `Count()` method performs some sort of query against the collection, where as `Count` must have already been assigned prior to me 'getting.' But that's a guess - I don't know if performance will be affected if I'm wrong.

EDIT: Out of curiosity then, will `Count()` throw an exception if the collection is null? Because I'm pretty sure the `Count` property simply returns 0.

Comment: Both will throw an exception for null collections, because both are trying to apply the `.` operator to something that is null.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Decompiling the source for the `Count()` extension method reveals that it tests whether the object is an `ICollection` (generic or otherwise) and if so simply returns the underlying `Count` property:

So, if your code accesses `Count` instead of calling `Count()`, you can bypass the type checking - a theoretical performance benefit but I doubt it would be a noticeable one!

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    checked
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        }
        ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            return collection.Count;
        }
        ICollection collection2 = source as ICollection;
        if (collection2 != null)
        {
            return collection2.Count;
        }
        int num = 0;
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for taking the initiative to reverse engineer this, very helpful.

Comment: However, bear in mind that in 3.5 `Count()` doesn't check for the non-generic `ICollection` interface. This was only added in .NET 4. Both 3.5 and 4 check for the generic `ICollection<T>` interface.

Comment: calling count on a sequence with no elements will throw an exception. But Count() will work fine.

Answer (score 43):

Performance is only one reason to choose one or the other.  Choosing `.Count()` means that your code will be more generic.  I've had occasions where I refactored some code that no longer produced a collection, but instead something more generic like an IEnumerable, but other code broke as a result because it depended on `.Count` and I had to change it to `.Count()`.  If I made a point to use `.Count()` everywhere, the code would likely be more reusable and maintainable.  Usually opting to utilize the more generic interfaces if you can get away with it is your best bet.  By more generic, I mean the simpler interface that is implemented by more types, and thus netting you greater compatibility between code.

I'm not saying `.Count()` is better, I'm just saying there's other considerations that deal more with the reusability of the code you are writing.

Comment: +1 Valuable addition to the discussion. Some code I am maintaining just broke because the property .Count did not survive a version upgrade of the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: That may be  double edged sword. What if some day someone tries to modify the IEnumerable to be a true generator. Looking at the codebase I see lot of places where the .Count() assumes that the enumerable can be iterated multiple times

Comment: @bashrc True. I think if we are considering developer's code changing versus framework code changing, it's more likely the developer code would change.  If that kind of change was made in the framework, it'd break alot of things.  Traditionally they introduce new collections/interfaces in these cases so that developer's can migrate as desired.

Answer (score 24):

The `.Count()` method *might* be smart enough, or know about the type in question, and if so, it *might* use the underlying `.Count` property.

Then again, it might not.

I would say it is safe to assume that if the collection has a `.Count` property itself, that's going to be your best bet when it comes to performance.

If the `.Count()` method doesn't know about the collection, it will enumerate over it, which will be an O(n) operation.

Comment: Using the `Count` property could be better, but `Count()` method making using `ICollection<T>.Count` is kinda documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't know how you know almost everything.

Answer (score 6):

Short Version: If you have the choice between a `Count` property and a `Count()` method always choose the property.

The difference is mainly around the efficiency of the operation.   All BCL collections which expose a `Count` property do so in an O(1) fashion.  The `Count()` method though can, and often will, cost O(N).  There are some checks to try and get it to O(1) for some implementations but it's by no means guaranteed.

Comment: I think this answer is more reasonable to use count property

Answer (score 5):

The `Count()` method is the LINQ method that works on any `IEnumerable<>`.  You would expect the `Count()` method to iterate over the whole collection to find the count, but I believe the LINQ code actually has some optimizations in there to detect if a Count property exists and if so use that.

So they should both do almost identical things.  The Count property is probably slightly better since there doesn't need to be a type check in there.

Answer (score 5):

`Count()` method is an extension method that iterates each element of an `IEnumerable<>` and returns how many elements are there. If the instance of `IEnumerable` is actually a `List<>`, so it's optimized to return the `Count` property instead of iterating all elements.

Comment: even when I have a List<>, I use Count() method to keep my code more generic. Its good when I'm refactoring my classes to use IEnumerable<> where there is no need of specific collection implementation.

Answer (score 4):

`Count()` is there as an extension method from LINQ - `Count` is a property on `List`s, actual .NET collection objects.

As such, `Count()` will almost always be slower, since it will enumerate the collection / queryable object.  On a list, queue, stack etc, use `Count`.  Or for an array - `Length`.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a `Count` or `Length` property, you should always prefer that to the `Count()` method, which generally iterates the entire collection to count the number of elements within. Exceptions would be when the `Count()` method is against a LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities source, for example, in which case it would perform a count query against the datasource.  Even then, if there is a `Count` property, you would want to prefer that, since it likely has less work to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `Count()` method has an optimisation for `ICollection<T>` which results in the `Count` property being called. In this case there is probably no significant difference in performance.

There are types other than `ICollection<T>` which have more efficient alternatives to the `Count()` extension method though. This code analysis performance rule fires on the following types.

[CA1829](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1829): Use Length/Count property instead of Enumerable.Count method

```
System.Array
System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<T>
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

So, we should use `Count` and `Length` properties if they are available and fallback to the `Count()` extension method otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`.Count` is a property of a collection and gets the elements in the collection. Unlike `.Count()` which is an extension method for LINQ and counts the number of elements.

Generally `.Count` is faster than `.Count()` because it does not require the overhead of creating and enumerating a LINQ query.

It's better to use the `.Count` property unless you need the additional functionality provided by the `.Count()` method, such as the ability to specify a filtering predicate, e.g.

```
int count = numbers.Count(n => n.Id == 100);
```