# Implementing Hoey Shamos algorithm with C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, computational-geometry, arcgis, c5

Okay, I am now getting the correct information from my current algorithm! However, with 700,000 polygons to check, it's just way too slow! The previous issue is fixed (My Line2D intersectsWith method was incorrect)

Now it's a matter of identifying my bottleneck! This algorithm is suppose to be O(nlog-n) so it should be much quicker. My intersectsWith method looks like it can't get any faster, however I will post its code, in case I'm wrong

**EDIT: Added IComparable interface**

My method for reading line segment intersections. Some code has been omitted for readability.

```
    public class Line2D : IComparable
    {


    public Line2D(XYPoints p1, XYPoints p2)
    {

    }

    public bool intersectsLine(Line2D comparedLine)
    {

        if ((X2 == comparedLine.X1) && (Y2 == comparedLine.Y1)) return false;
        if ((X1 == comparedLine.X2) && (Y1 == comparedLine.Y2)) return false;

        if (X2 == comparedLine.X1 && Y2 == comparedLine.Y1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (X1 == comparedLine.X2 && Y1 == comparedLine.Y2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double firstLineSlopeX, firstLineSlopeY, secondLineSlopeX, secondLineSlopeY;

        firstLineSlopeX = X2 - X1;
        firstLineSlopeY = Y2 - Y1;

        secondLineSlopeX = comparedLine.getX2() - comparedLine.getX1();
        secondLineSlopeY = comparedLine.getY2() - comparedLine.getY1();

        double s, t;
        s = (-firstLineSlopeY * (X1 - comparedLine.getX1()) + firstLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);
        t = (secondLineSlopeX * (getY1() - comparedLine.getY1()) - secondLineSlopeY * (getX1() - comparedLine.getX1())) / (-secondLineSlopeX * firstLineSlopeY + firstLineSlopeX * secondLineSlopeY);

        if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false; // No collision 
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
    {

        //return Y1.GetHashCode();
        Line2D o1 = this;
        Line2D o2 = (Line2D)obj;
        if (o1.getY1() < o2.getY1())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (o1.getY1() > o2.getY2())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (o1.getY2() < o2.getY2())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (o1.getY2() > o2.getY2())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        } 
    }


}
```

The bulk of my algorithm implementation, I realize a List isn't the fastest for an  algorithm, however I need indexing!:

```
//Create a new list, sort by Y values.

 List<AlgEvent> SortedList = events.OrderBy(o => o.getY()).ToList();                
 List<Line2D> sweepline = new List<Line2D>();

 for (var g = 0; g < SortedList.Count; g++)
 {
 if (SortedList[g].isStart)
 {
    Line2D nl = SortedList[g].line;
    Line2D above;
    /* Start generating above */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        if (index == -1)
        {
            above = null;
        }
        else
        {
            above = sweepline[index + 1];
        }


    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        above = null;
    }
    /* End generating above */
    if (above != null)
    {
        if (above.intersectsLine(nl))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    Line2D below;
    /* Start generating below */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        below = sweepline[index - 1];

    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {

        below = null;

    }
    /* End generating below */
    if (below != null)
    {
        if (below.intersectsLine(nl))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    sweepline.Add(nl);
    sweepline = sweepline.OrderBy(o => o.getY1()).ToList();

}
else
{
    Line2D nl = SortedList[g].line;
    Line2D above;
    Line2D below;
    /* Start generating above */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("index:" + index);
        //add 1 to get above line
        above = sweepline[index + 1];

    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {

        above = null;

    }
    /* End generating above */
    /* Start generating below */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        below = sweepline[index - 1];

    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {

        below = null;

    }
    /* End generating below */
    sweepline = sweepline.OrderBy(o => o.getY1()).ToList();
    sweepline.Remove(nl);
    if (above != null && below != null)
    {
        if (above.intersectsLine(below))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("");
  }



   } // end numofparts for-loop

   return false;
```

============================================

UPDATE: September 12th:
Implemented the TreeSet from C5, implemented IComparable to my classes, and slowed it down even more? I am still indexing it if that matters?

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Code using TreeSet:

```
TreeSet<Line2D> sweepline = new TreeSet<Line2D>();
for (var g = 0; g < SortedList.Count; g++)
{
if (SortedList[g].isStart)
{
    Line2D nl = SortedList[g].line;
    Line2D above;
    /* Start generating above */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        above = sweepline[index + 1];

    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {

        above = null;

    }
    /* End generating above */
    if (above != null)
    {
        if (above.intersectsLine(nl))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    Line2D below;
    /* Start generating below */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        below = sweepline[index - 1];

    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {

        below = null;

    }
    /* End generating below */
    if (below != null)
    {
        if (below.intersectsLine(nl))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    sweepline.Add(nl);
    //sweepline = sweepline.OrderBy(o => o.getY1()).ToList();

}
else
{
    Line2D nl = SortedList[g].line;
    Line2D above;
    Line2D below;
    /* Start generating above */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //Console.Out.WriteLine("index:" + index);
        //add 1 to get above line
        above = sweepline[index + 1];

    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {

        above = null;

    }
    /* End generating above */
    /* Start generating below */
    try
    {
        //grab index in sweepline
        int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
        //add 1 to get above line
        below = sweepline[index - 1];

    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {

        below = null;

    }
    /* End generating below */
    //sweepline = sweepline.OrderBy(o => o.getY1()).ToList();
    sweepline.Remove(nl);
    if (above != null && below != null)
    {
        if (above.intersectsLine(below))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
//Console.WriteLine("");
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't implement TreeSet in C#, yourself?

Comment: So you're basically saying I could extend the OrderedSet class, and add the higher and lower methods?

Comment: @EvanParsons I think Zac is saying implement a TreeSet from scratch. TreeSet and the like use a *balanced tree* data structure (e.g. a Red-Black tree or an AVL tree) but these aren't simple to implement. A skip list is a much simpler data structure that would do the job though.

Comment: @john:  That is correct, though, implementing a tree data structure is far more simple than trying to force a data structure that doesn't suit the requirement of the algorithm into working with it (square peg meet round whole).  While a skip list will work (though the algorithm code will be a bit harder to write), an ordered set would not.

Comment: I think I have an idea. I'm going to use a try-catch block. I'll use a list and use "indexOf" to return the position. If it returns -1, or an argument not within range of the List, I'll make it return null.

Comment: In general, you use a heap based structure for the event queue, and a balanced binary search tree for the Y structure. The lists you use would make things slower.. The said nlogn complexity is using these data structures if i remember correctly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regarding the line intersection: you do not need the actual point of intersection, only to know if they intersect. See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/ for an algorithm that does just that.

---

About the `List` implementation:

In your implementation using `List`s, you call `indexOf` on the sweepline to find `nl`. This searches the sweepline from start to end. See [`List(T).IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx). If you were to use the [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method, that ought to speed up the search considerably.

[List's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) has a paragraph called performance considerations. They urge you to use a value type that implements `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`. So, your `Line2D` should probably be a `struct` and implement these interfaces.

If you follow that advice, retrieval of the endpoint from the sweepline should be O(log n), which is sufficient for your purpose, and memory should be used more efficiently.

Insertion and removal are O(n) for Lists, cause the underlying array needs to be moved around in memory. A `SortedSet` has faster insertion and removal, but I don't quite see how to find an item's neighbors in O(log n) there. Anyone? (See also [Why SortedSet<T>.GetViewBetween isn't O(log N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n))

---

Anyways, the C5 `TreeSet` should solve this.

I looked up the performance of IndexOf and [i] in the [user guide](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/PreRelease0.5/userguide.htm#mozTocId336849) and they're both listed as O(log n). So that is not supposed to be the issue. It's still probably somewhat faster, but no more than a fixed factor, to call the specific methods for finding the neighbors on the sweepline, i.e. [Successor](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet%601.htm#T:C5.TreeSet%601%7CM:C5.TreeSet%601.Successor%28%600%29) and [Predecessor](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet%601.htm#T:C5.TreeSet%601%7CM:C5.TreeSet%601.Predecessor%28%600%29), which are also O(log n).

So

```
[...]
try 
{
    Line2D above = sweepline.Successor(nl);
    if (above.intersectsLine(nl))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
catch (NoSuchItemException ignore) { }
[...]
```

I don't like that they do not have a method that doesn't throw the exception, since throwing exceptions is very expensive. Your sweep line will be pretty full generally so my best guess is that failure to find one will be rare and calling `Successor` is the most efficient way. Alternatively, you could keep calling `IndexOf` like you do now, but check if it equals `Count` minus one before retrieving `[index + 1]`, and prevent the exception from being thrown at all:

```
[...]
int index = sweepline.IndexOf(nl);
if( index < sweepline.Count-1 )
{
    Line2D above = sweepline[index + 1];
    if (above.intersectsLine(nl))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
[...]
```

Chapter two of the [manual](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/latest/ITU-TR-2006-76.pdf) describes equality and comparison for C5 collections. Here, too, at the very least you must implement `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`!

One more thought: you report feeding the algorithm 700000 lines. Could you start with timing for example 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000 lines and seeing how the algorithm scales for cases where they do not intersect?

---

On how to compare the lines on the sweepline:

You need to find some sort of natural ordering for the Line2Ds on the Sweepline TreeSet, since the CompareTo method asks you to compare one Line2D to another. One of the Line2Ds already sits in the Sweepline TreeSet, the other has just been encountered and is being added.

Your sweepline runs from bottom to top, I think:

```
List<AlgEvent> SortedList = events.OrderBy(o => o.getY()).ToList();
```

[image: Sweepline running through the line segments]

So let's say segment S1 got added to the TreeSet at event 1, and we wish to compare it to S2, which is being added at event 2, right now.

The line segments could possibly intersect at some point, which would change the ordering, but the algorithm will check for this right after inserting them, in the above and below checks. Which would perhaps better be called the left and right checks, come to think of it.

Anyways.. so the easiest would be to compare the bottom endpoints of both line segments. To the left is smaller, to the right is bigger. However, we need to look at the ordering at the position of the sweepline and they may have changed positions since then, like in the picture.

So we need to compare the bottom endpoint of S2 to the red point on S1, and see if it lies to the left or to the right of that point. It lies to the left so S2 is considered smaller than S1.

Usually it's simpler than this: If all of S1 lies to the left of S2's bottom endpoint, S1 is smaller than S2. If all of S1 lies to the right of S2's bottom endpoint, S1 is larger than S2.

I think you're looking for the typesafer version of the interface:

```
public class Line2D : IComparable<Line2D>
```

Assuming two properties `BottomY`, the lowest of the two Y values, and `BottomX`, the X value of the lowest endpoint, a somewhat tested attempt:

```
int IComparable<Line2D>.CompareTo(Line2D other)
{
    if( BottomY < other.BottomY )
    {
        return -other.CompareTo(this);
    }

    // we're the segment being added to the sweepline
    if( BottomX >= other.X1 && BottomX >= other.X2 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if( BottomX <= other.X1 && BottomX <= other.X2 )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if( other.Y2 == other.Y1 )
    {
        // Scary edge case: horizontal line that we intersect with. Return 0?
        return 0;
    }

    // calculate the X coordinate of the intersection of the other segment
    // with the sweepline
    // double redX = other.X1 + 
    //    (BottomY - other.Y1) * (other.X2 - other.X1) / (other.Y2 - other.Y1);
    //
    // return BottomX.CompareTo(redX);

    // But more efficient, and more along the lines of the orientation comparison:
    return Comparer<Double>.Default.Compare(
        (BottomX - other.X1) * (other.Y2 - other.Y1),
        (BottomY - other.Y1) * (other.X2 - other.X1) );

}
```

Comment: I could limit the data to reading only 100,000 at a time. Would be easier and faster than reading 700,000 at a time then recording the time.

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing IComparable. Right now it returns 600,000 "invalid" polygons. Which is definitely false. I'll update my original post with the revised Line2D class.

Comment: I've added some thoughts on how to compare the Line2Ds.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused, will take some time to try and comprehend and report back, thanks again!

Comment: I thought my line was sweeping left to right. I was organizing them by Y's since it's encountering them when it sweeps L-T-R. This is the first time I've seen bottom Y, other bottom Y used in this algorithm. I haven't implemented IEquatable yet, but I did override getHashCode and the Equals method.

Comment: I based my code originally on this code (was Java, but C# is similar)
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-this-implementation-of-shamos-hoey-algorithm-ok

Comment: If you wish to sweep from left to right, you'll have to sort the events on X value, not Y, I think. And rewrite to leftmostx and y rather than bottomx and y. This is a bit funny cause I had just turned my mental model 90 degrees counterclockwise to accommodate your sweepline direction. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37531/discussion-between-flup-and-evan-parsons)

Comment: Hey flup, SO doesn't allow IM's but could you give me an email through  http://www.evanparsons.net/contact.aspx I'm so close. I think the issue comes down to my IComparable, but I can't be too sure. I'm hitting a wall on this.

Answer (score 1):

**[original answer]**

I am not **C#** user, but this should speeds things up a little.

- less heap trashing
- do not compute the same thing twice
- avoid all sub calls if you can (get functions removed)

code:

```
public bool intersectsLine(const Line2D &comparedLine)
    {
    if ((X2==comparedLine.X1)&&(Y2==comparedLine.Y1)) return false;
    if ((X1==comparedLine.X2)&&(Y1==comparedLine.Y2)) return false;
    double dx1,dy1,dx2,dy2;
    dx1 = X2 - X1;
    dy1 = Y2 - Y1;
    dx2 = comparedLine.X2 - comparedLine.X1;
    dy2 = comparedLine.Y2 - comparedLine.Y1;
    double s,t,ax,ay,b;
    ax=X1-comparedLine.X1;
    ay=Y1-comparedLine.Y1;
    b=1.0/(-(dx2*dy1)+(dx1*dy2));
    s = (-(dy1*ax)+(dx1*ay))*b;
    t = ( (dx2*ay)-(dy2*ax))*b;
    if ((s>=0)&&(s<=1)&&(t>=0)&&(t<=1)) return true;
    return false; // No collision
    }
```

for the rest of your code, add time measurements to find what exactly slow things down. My guess is on List management ... unnecessary reallocations can slow things considerably.

**[edit1]**

After some research on random line data I concluded this:

1. if too many lines are across the entire area than no optimizations are valid
2. if there are more small lines than there is more speedup for any optimizations
3. brute force is `T((N*N-N)/2)` which is still `O(N*N)`
   estimate around 35 hours for 700K lines to be processed (unusable)
4. optimized brute force with area subdivision is `T((((N/M)^2)-N)/2)` - optimizations `~O((N/M)^2)` where

   - `N` is max of area lines number
   - `M` is number of area divisions per any axis
     idea is to check only lines crossing some region (divide dataset area to `M*M` squares/rectangles). For 700K lines is best subdivision to `16x16` areas. Measured times:

     0.540s per  32K lines
     1.950s per  64K lines
     7.000s per 128K lines
     27.514s per 256K lines

   estimated run time is 3.7 min per 700K lines **(for lines at max ~10% length of whole area)**. I think this is better than yours 19 minutes.
5. another speed up is possible with use of multi CPU/core

   algorithm is fully parallel-isable and for 4 CPU/Cores `3.7min/4 -> 56s` or you can port it to GPU ...

**My optimized brute force algorithm with area subdivision O((((N/M)^2)-N)/2) - optimizations**

1. get the used area size `(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)` `O(N)`
2. select subdivision `M`
   the best I try for my random datasets `32K-256K` lines was `M=16`
3. cycle through all subdivision area (evenly divided dataset area)

   create list of lines crossing actual subdivision area and check intersection for all lines in that list. If do not want duplicate intersections then discard all intersection outside current area

my code (I am using **BDS2006 C++** and my own lists so you need to port it to be compatible with your code)

```
void Twin_GLView2D::main_intersect(int M=16)
{
int ia,ib,i,j,N;
double zero=1e-6;
glview2D::_lin *l;
glview2D::_pnt p;

struct _line
    {
    double bx0,by0,bx1,by1;     // bounding rectangle
    double x0,y0,dx,dy;         // precomputed params
    } *lin,*a,*b;

struct _siz
    {
    double bx0,bx1,by0,by1;     // zone bounding rectangle
    } sz,bz;
List<_line*> zone;

// load and precompute lines
N=view.lin.num;
lin=new _line[N];
if (lin==NULL) return;
for (a=lin,l=view.lin.dat,ia=0;ia<N;ia++,a++,l++)
    {
    // line ...
    if (l->p0.p[0]<=l->p1.p[0]) { a->bx0=l->p0.p[0]; a->bx1=l->p1.p[0]; }
    else                        { a->bx0=l->p1.p[0]; a->bx1=l->p0.p[0]; }
    if (l->p0.p[1]<=l->p1.p[1]) { a->by0=l->p0.p[1]; a->by1=l->p1.p[1]; }
    else                        { a->by0=l->p1.p[1]; a->by1=l->p0.p[1]; }
    a->x0=l->p0.p[0]; a->dx=l->p1.p[0]-l->p0.p[0];
    a->y0=l->p0.p[1]; a->dy=l->p1.p[1]-l->p0.p[1];
    // global image size for zone subdivision
    if (!ia)
        {
        sz.bx0=l->p0.p[0];
        sz.by0=l->p0.p[1];
        sz.bx1=sz.bx0;
        sz.by1=sz.by0;
        }
    if (sz.bx0>l->p0.p[0]) sz.bx0=l->p0.p[0];
    if (sz.bx1<l->p0.p[0]) sz.bx1=l->p0.p[0];
    if (sz.by0>l->p0.p[1]) sz.by0=l->p0.p[1];
    if (sz.by1<l->p0.p[1]) sz.by1=l->p0.p[1];
    if (sz.bx0>l->p1.p[0]) sz.bx0=l->p1.p[0];
    if (sz.bx1<l->p1.p[0]) sz.bx1=l->p1.p[0];
    if (sz.by0>l->p1.p[1]) sz.by0=l->p1.p[1];
    if (sz.by1<l->p1.p[1]) sz.by1=l->p1.p[1];
    }
// process lines by zonal subdivision
zone.allocate(N);
view.pnt.num=0; view.pnt.allocate(view.lin.num);
sz.bx1-=sz.bx0; sz.bx1/=double(M);
sz.by1-=sz.by0; sz.by1/=double(M);
for (bz.by0=sz.by0,bz.by1=sz.by0+sz.by1,i=0;i<M;i++,bz.by0+=sz.by1,bz.by1+=sz.by1)
for (bz.bx0=sz.bx0,bz.bx1=sz.bx0+sz.bx1,j=0;j<M;j++,bz.bx0+=sz.bx1,bz.bx1+=sz.bx1)
    {
    // create list of lines for actual zone only
    zone.num=0;         // clear zone list
    for (a=lin,ia=   0;ia<N;ia++,a++)
     if ((a->bx0<=bz.bx1)&&(a->bx1>=bz.bx0))
      if ((a->by0<=bz.by1)&&(a->by1>=bz.by0))
       zone.add(a); // add line to zone list
    // check for intersection within zone only
    // O((((N/M)^2)-N)/2) - optimizations
    for (ia=   0,a=zone.dat[ia];ia<zone.num;ia++,a=zone.dat[ia])
    for (ib=ia+1,b=zone.dat[ib];ib<zone.num;ib++,b=zone.dat[ib])
        {
        // discart lines with non intersecting bound rectangles
        if (a->bx1<b->bx0) continue;
        if (a->bx0>b->bx1) continue;
        if (a->by1<b->by0) continue;
        if (a->by0>b->by1) continue;
        // 2D lines a,b intersect ?
        double x0,y0,x1,y1,t0,t1;
        // compute intersection
        t1=divide(a->dx*(a->y0-b->y0)+a->dy*(b->x0-a->x0),(a->dx*b->dy)-(b->dx*a->dy));
        x1=b->x0+(b->dx*t1);
        y1=b->y0+(b->dy*t1);
        if (fabs(a->dx)>=fabs(a->dy)) t0=divide(b->x0-a->x0+(b->dx*t1),a->dx);
        else                          t0=divide(b->y0-a->y0+(b->dy*t1),a->dy);
        x0=a->x0+(a->dx*t0);
        y0=a->y0+(a->dy*t0);
        // check if intersection exists
        if (fabs(x1-x0)>zero) continue;
        if (fabs(y1-y0)>zero) continue;
        if ((t0<0.0)||(t0>1.0)) continue;
        if ((t1<0.0)||(t1>1.0)) continue;
        // if yes add point
        p.p[0]=x0;
        p.p[1]=y0;
        p.p[2]=0.0;
        // do not add points out of zone (allmost all duplicit points removal)
        if (x0<bz.bx0) continue;
        if (x0>bz.bx1) continue;
        if (y0<bz.by0) continue;
        if (y0>bz.by1) continue;
        view.pnt.add(p);
        }
    }
view.redraw=true;
delete lin;
}
```

Notes:

1. `List<T> x;`  is the same as `T x[]` with 'unlimited' size

   - `x.num;` is actual size of `x[]` in Ts not Bytes !!! `index = <0,x.num-1>`
   - `x.add(q);` adds `q` to the list at the end
   - `x.num=0;` clears the list
   - `x.allocate(N);` allocate space for `N` items in list to avoid relocations
2. input `List<>` is `view.lin`  ... contains points `p0,p1` each have `double p[2]` ... `x,y`
3. output `List<>` is `view.pnt` ... contains `double p[2]` ... `x,y`

**[Edit2]**

In addition I found out that the best performance of above algorithm is when `M=12+(N>>15)`

- `M` is subdivision areas count per axis
- `N` is number of lines to check

Comment: you may be on to something for speed. The supplied code you have there is no faster than mine, however, when I force my "intersectsLine" method to return true or false, it completes in 19 minutes, rather than just timing out. Is there a faster way to detect if an intersection occured? (Exact point isn't needed)

Comment: hard to say without knowing your dataset properties,... usually clever reorder sorting and or unimportant data removal leads to big speed increase.

Comment: can you post your dataset example somewhere ? so anyone can test ... its 2D so svg or ASCII text-file export will be fine. P.S. my version of intersectsLine isnt faster on execution, but in heap trashing and overhead. So if you measure time for single shot there should be no much difference. but if you loop its call 10000 x times than you should measure the difference. , also wanted result example will be interesting to see.

Comment: Just have added some interesting info so check it out. (i need the exact intersection points) the only downside of my algorithm is that if the intersection is exactly on the area boundary than it will by duplicating itself).

Comment: I'm going to try your brute force approach tonight. I should mention that it's 700,000 polygons with between 5 to 4,500 lines in each polygon.

Comment: wow thats a huge amount of data how much memory do you have (maybe you do not have speed issues but memory issues)? My algorithm is optimized for use with lines (i need it to be like that) for better polygon optimization you should first check only bounding rectangles of all polygons and discard all non intersecting ones that should ease up a bit everything and memory requirements for that is not big (min,max * num of dimensions and intersect flag  for each polygon).

Comment: I read the 700,000 from a binary file, no memory issues to speak of.

Comment: oh yes i forget that you do not need the intersection points, just flag if polygon intersects. In my case for 700K+ lines the mem tables get big. btw how are your results? if you can share one rared/zipped dataset with format info i would like to try to code and test it myself for fun ( :-) and i think it will be useful for me in time anyway) of course i hope the arch-file is not 1GB :) or confidential

Comment: I can't share the data unfortunately, I did however update my code for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386108/implementing-an-algorithm-for-detecting-a-self-intersecting-polygon