# Intersection points between a long list of segments

Tags: matlab, loops, geometry, computational-geometry, line-intersection

I'm writing a Matlab program that has to do the following thing I'm stuck with.

I have a file containing the names of two points on every line (the points have its respective coordinates in the space). Let's say the segments are airways and the points are airports.

I have plotted all the airways, and obviously some of them intersect at some point. I would like to draw a cross 'X' at those points of intersection. How can I do this? Is there any already-implemented Matlab function that allows me to find the intersection points of segments?

And another question related to this, provided the file (with about 100 lines, where in every line a segment is defined by two points) should I do a loop that checks all the intersecting points of the first segment with the other 99 segments, and then the second segment with the other 98 segments? Or there is a more efficient way in order to do that? Thank you!!!

Comment: look at `polyxpoly` http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html

Comment: Warning: `polyxpoly` is only available if you have the Mapping toolbox.

Comment: 100 segments is not long list (I am not using Matlab but even there should not be 100 line a big problem). look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18739791/2521214 for speed up ideas

Comment: Thanks so much @Spektre !! I finally got it!