# Java Nearest Intersection

Tags: java, geometry, intersection

I am making my own implementation of a raycaster in a game I am making, and I have come across a very hard problem. I have a player (the black dot), and I need to find the intersection **nearest** to the player. In the image below, the arrow is pointing to the intersection point I need.

[image: Nearest Intersection Example]

What I guess I am trying to say is that I need a function something like this:

```
// Each line would take in 2 map values for it's 2 points
// In turn, the map would have to have an even number of points

public Point getNearestIntersection(int playerX, int playerY, int lineDir, Point[] map) {
    // whatever goes here
}
```

I am going to have to do this about 50 times every frame, with about 100 lines. I would like to get 40 fps at the least if possible... Even if I divide it up into threads I still feel that it would cause a lot of lag.

Comment: Is computing the intersection the problem or which one is nearest?

Comment: @Fildor which one is nearest

Comment: I'd suggest using a library. Jbox2d is pretty good, it supports something called bullet physics which is what I think you're looking for.

Comment: It seems you have to add ray direction as function parameter. And about lines - are they really lines or segments? About efficiency - is `map` static for multpile player queries?

Answer (score 2):

The class `Point` has a method called `distance` which calculates the distance of two points. You then could loop all points to get the nearest. Could be something like this:

```
Point currentNearestIntersection;
double smallestDistance;

for (Point inter : intersections) {
    double distance = player.distance(inter );
    if (distance < smallestDistance) {
        currentNearestIntersection= inter;
        smallestDistance = distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do this about 50 times every frame it renders, and with 100 lines, I think that this would cause a HUGE amount of lag. Though I fear this may be my only option...

Comment: Nevermind, I just added that information to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**axis/line intersection** is in reality solving:

```
p(t)=p0+dp*t
q(u)=q0+(q1-q0)*u
p(t)=q(u)
t=? u=?
```

where:

- `p0` is your ray start point (vector)
- `dp` is ray direction (vector)
- `q0,q1` are line endpoints (vectors)
- `p(t),q(u)` are points on axis,line
- `t,u` are line parameters (scalars)

This is simple system of 2 linear equations (but in vectors) so it lead to N solutions where N is the dimensionality of the problem so choose the one that is not division by zero ... Valid result is if:

- `t>=0` and `u=<0.0,1.0>`

if you use unit `dp` vector for direction of your ray then from computing intersection between axis and line the `t` parameter is directly distance from the ray start point. So you can directly use that ...

if you need to speed up the intersections computation see

- [brute force line/line intersection with area subdivision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739791/2521214)

And instead of remebering all intersections store always the one with smallest but non negative `t` ...

**[Notes]**

if you got some lines as a grid then you can compute that even faster exploiting **DDA** algorithm and use real line/line intersection only for the iregular rest... nice example of this is Wolfenstein pseudo 3D raycaster problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733650/2521214)