# What is the difference between count (*) and count(attribute_name)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, count

Is there any difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(attribute_name)?

I used count(attribute_name) as I thought that it would be specific hence the searching process would be easier. Is that true?

It would be great to see any example with sql code with my issue to help me understand better

Comment: Count(*) will return number of rows in the table. Count(colname) will return number of non null rows for that particular column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count property vs Count() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969354/count-property-vs-count-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this table:

[image]

```
select Count(TelephoneNumber) from Calls -- returns 3
select Count(*) from Calls -- returns 4
```

count(column_name) also counts duplicate values. Consider:

[image]

```
select Count(TelephoneNumber) from Calls -- returns 4
```

Comment: I understand your explanation the most! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(*)` counts all the records in the group.

`COUNT(column_name)` only counts non-null values.

There is also another typical expression, `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)`, that counts non-null distinct values.

Since you asked for it, here is a **[demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1b5392c1e66d5fe5f8ecfde14a09255)**:

```
with t as (
    select 1 x from dual
    union all select 1 from dual
    union all select null from dual
)
select count(*), count(x), count(distinct x) from t
```

```
COUNT(*) | COUNT(X) | COUNT(DISTINCTX)
-------: | -------: | ---------------:
       3 |        2 |                1
```

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` will count all the rows.
`COUNT(column)` will count `non-NULLs` only.

Your can use of `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(column)` which should be based on the desired output only.

Consider below Example of employee table

```
ID        Name      Description
1         Raji      Smart
2         Rahi      Positive
3 
4         Falle     Smart
```

select count(*) from employee;

```
Count(*)
4
```

select count(name) from employee;

```
Count(Name)
3
```

Comment: count(Column Name) counts duplicate rows.

Comment: added example for avoiding confusion

Comment: so that means if I use count(*), it will count all data in the table even if the row has no data. Right?

Comment: this explanation is kinda confusing

Comment: yes exactly count(*) will count row with null values also where as count(column) doesnt..what is confusing please let me know...i have provided very simple example..if you have any example i can explain much better..

Comment: okay thank you! I need some time to understand this concept. I will try to do some exercise to make it clear for me

Answer (score 1):

`count()` only counts non-null values. `*` references the complete row and as such never excludes any rows. `count(attribute_name)` only counts rows where that column is no null.

So this:

```
select count(attribute_name)
from the_table
```

is equivalent to:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where attribute_name is not null
```

Comment: so that means if I use count(attribute_name), it will count all data in the table even if the row has no data. Right?

Comment: No, the opposite: It will count all rows where the _column_ **does** contain data. Look at the second query

Answer (score -1):

The difference is simple: **COUNT(*)** counts the number of rows produced by the query, whereas **COUNT(1)** counts the number of **1** values. Note that when you include a literal such as a number or a string in a query, this literal is "appended" or attached to every row that is produced by the **FROM** clause.

For more detail [this](https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/COUNT-or-COUNT-1) link would help you understand.