# Does .Where(x=> x.listFoos.Count() > 1) count all sub element?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of object with a property of type List:

```
class Bar{
   public List<Foo> Foos{get;set;}
}
```

Will the following code, that select all bar with more than one Foo,  count all Foos?
Or will it stop iterating at 2 Foos?

```
var input = new List<Bar>();
var result = input.Where(x=> x.Foos.Count()>1).ToList();
```

Comment: The code, as shown, will not count any Foos since Where is lazily evaluated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969354/count-property-vs-count-method

Comment: An alternative, to prevent iterating an entire enumerable (i.e. when it's not `ICollection<T>`) is to use `input.Skip(1).Any()`.

Comment: When using LinQ Count(), you expect something to be enumerate. Limiting this Count in a Where clause "Is there more than one item?" is normal to expect only to count to 1. That's a contradiction with the count tho the question.

Comment: @MartinBackasch: Well x => **c**.Foos... won't even compile, so I assumed `Count()` (instead of `Count`) to be a typo as well.

Comment: The c was a typo. It's x. I typed in SO directly. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: @Heinzi: ah sorry, I missed that x => c change. I only looked at the title and the `Count` within the body.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I have taken the liberty of adding your comment to my answer (it's too useful to be lost in a comment).

Comment: @HansKilian, Yes, it's lazy, but `input` is an empty list so `x.Foos` is null.  it will at least throw a null exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't count anything. `List<T>` redundantly stores the number of elements, so accessing the `Count` property [is a `O(1)` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netcore-3.1).

This works even if you use the `Enumerable.Count()` extension method rather than `List<T>`s built-in `Count` property, because `Enumerable.Count()` [has a built-in optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969468/87698) if the underlying data source implements `ICollection<T>`.

---

As mentioned by Enigmativity in the comments: If you have an IEnumerable which is *not* an `ICollection<T>`, you can use the following instead to prevent iterating the entire enumerable:

```
var result = input.Where(x => x.Foos.Skip(1).Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: I expected the : "No,It won't count". But I expected it to be because in some kind of expression tree, this yield to that , and it's stop enumerating. Not count doesn't count on ICollection.

Comment: @DragandDrop: As far as I know LINQ-to-objects (as opposed to LINQ-to-SQL or EF) does not use expression tree evaluation. Thus, `Count()` will either be executed or it won't, and if it is executed, it won't know the context (`... > 1`) in which it is used.

Comment: For everything inside the `System.Collections`, that's almost everything the light touch, it won't because of the [optimisation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1314). 
I was perhaps to simple, I "_Expected_" count to count and linQ to be trees that get evaluated. But C# dev are smarter than me, here count is faster than skip().any, Because it's a simple type check access a property versus a getEnumerator etc. So even if it knew the context it doesn't need to.

Comment: When I said I was not expecting, I did not disapproved in any way the answer. I had a simple Where Count, and asked myself perhaps it count to much. And it does not. I fantasize about how it solve a problem it didn't have.

Answer (score 3):

When you have questions about how parts of .Net works it's ideal to look at the
[source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

this is source for List.Count

```
    // Read-only property describing how many elements are in the List.
    public int Count {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            return _size; 
        }
    }
```

`_size` is changed whenever the underlying collection is changed, so it doesn't actually count it just references the known size of the list.